# how to set yii2 Html::icon prefix to font-awesome 'fa fa-' with Dependency Injection Container?

Tags: dependency-injection, icons, yii2, font-awesome

How to set yii2 Html::icon prefix to font-awesome 'fa fa-' with Dependency Injection Container ?

Like this  is work.
`\Yii::$container->set('yii\widgets\LinkPager', ['maxButtonCount' => 5]);`

But i set `Yii::$container->set('yii\bootstrap\Html\icon', ['prefix' => 'fa fa-']);` not work....

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Yii2 guide about DI](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/concept-di-container.md)

> A dependency injection (DI) container is an object that knows how to
>   instantiate and configure objects and all their dependent objects.

The result of `static` method `Html::icon()` is a string. So you shoudn't use DI for this. Instead create your own `Html` class and nested `icon()`, then add it to bootstrap.

/web/index.php

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');
```

/config/bootstrap.php

```
Yii::$container->set('yii\bootstrap\Html', 'common\bootstrap\Html');
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I understand the wrong direction. This issue should not be solved.
I consider using static function but still thanks